# List of used index coluns (mysql/mariadb)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

`EXPLAIN` shows only key length.

For example:

We have an complex index on a table.

`IDX_KEY (col1, col2, col3)` (let's all the columns are integer type)

if the key length (from "explain" output) = 4 then only the `col1` of `IDX_KEY` index is used in the query.

if 8 then `col1` and `col2`.

if 12 then all the columns in the index are used.

My question: is there a way to determine columns list without calculations?

**UPD:**

The real table has a lot of fields and indexes. But for example, let it has such definition: `` CREATE TABLE `tbl` (`col1` unsigned int not null,`col2` unsigned int not null,`col3` unsigned int not null, primary key (`col1`,`col2`,`col2`)); ``

Then the explain can be like this (in case of using only one column from the index):

```
"id"  "select_type"  "table"  "type"   "possible_keys"  "key"      "key_len"  "ref"  "rows"  "Extra"
"1"   "PRIMARY"      "tbl"    "range"  "PRIMARY"        "PRIMARY"  "4"        \N     "1"     ""
```

Comment: Please add your table definition and the explain.AND I don't understand your question what does 'determine columns list' mean?

Comment: @P.Salmon the OP would like to know which columns from a multi-column index was used in the query. Could be an interesting data point for optimising indexes.

Comment: sample definition was added to the quiestion

Comment: Explain and explain extended does not have this information. Have you tried tracing the optimiser and see if that output has this info?

Comment: I need only understand is there any way to get the used columns list in the selected index without calculating with **key_len**. I no need to do some optimizations yet - just get the columns list.

Comment: Good question. I don't know how to determine if the SQL planner uses the the full length of indexes or just parts of them. Nowadays, the engine also offers JSON execution plans that offer more details on it. Maybe you can look into them.

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`

Comment: @RickJames, thank you. With "format" option I got what I need.

Comment: @Vitaly - Still there are cases where that won't suffice -- keep in mind that an index might be used for some combination of `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, and (indirectly) `LIMIT`.

Comment: Another cool thing from `FORMAT=JSON` -- how many sorts there are.

Comment: @RickJames, yes, I know about other constuctions used keys, but in my case the SQL-query was big, but not too complex. There is only one `GROUP BY` on another table column. It's strange for me that I missed `FORMAT=JSON` option considering that I used mysql/mariadb for a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relying on the key length makes no sense, as it depends on the storage engine and MariaDB version used. In the current MariaDB version (10.5) and InnoDB, the key length is not 4 but 5.

To get more information from the optimizer you should use ANALYZE command. Using it together with FORMAT=JSON (this feature is available since MariaDB 10.1) it will give you some more detailed information, including the used keys.

```
MariaDB [test]> analyze format=JSON select col1,col2,col3 from t2 where col1=1 and col2=2 \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
ANALYZE: {
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "r_loops": 1,
    "r_total_time_ms": 0.082303568,
    "table": {
      "table_name": "t2",
      "access_type": "ref",
      "possible_keys": ["col1"],
      "key": "col1",
      "key_length": "10",
      "used_key_parts": ["col1", "col2"],
      "ref": ["const", "const"],
      "r_loops": 1,
      "rows": 1,
      "r_rows": 1,
      "r_table_time_ms": 0.027733218,
      "r_other_time_ms": 0.041487106,
      "filtered": 100,
      "r_filtered": 100,
      "using_index": true
    }
  }
}
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

**Addendum**: I didn't see the comment from Rick James before, the `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` works too, and if you only need the used keys you should use this command.

Comment: Cool command! Unfortunately, it's not applied to mysql, but it'll be useful for me for future. Thanks.

Comment: But afaik MySQL supports EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON

Comment: Yes, it returns a bit more data than `analyze`, but contains need data.

Comment: For `INT`, `5` indicates that the column is `NULLable`, `4` indicates `NOT NULL`.